# S3 Bucket Policy for PostObject - Timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm having some problem uploading files from my webapp to AWS S3. It appears like there is a timeout happening (at S3 end) and because of this, my script is restarting and as a result of this, the uploaded contents are being duplicated. If i disable S3 and upload to my local server, the files are perfectly getting uploaded with no duplicates.

I was wondering if I could add a PutObject policy on the S3 bucket and set a timeout. However, I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.